# Collision response with spring physics in RK4

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision, computational-physics, spring, software

I'm trying to figure out what's in the title. I've gotten regular spring physics working and now I'm trying to do something similar with actual collisions (player character colliding with the ground in a game at the moment).

I have an RK4 integrator running in my update loop and I think the only thing I'm missing is the formula that I should use. I've been reading [this](https://gafferongames.com/post/spring_physics/) and I think I need to use the following formula: **F=nkd-bn(n.v)** where n is the contact normal, k and b are the spring damping coefficients, d is the desired distance of seperation, and v is the relative velocity between the two points connected by the spring.

I need it split up in an x and y value so this is what I've made of it so far:

```
var n = [0, -1];  // collision normal
var k = 1, b = 1; // spring coefficients
var sceneStates = [[posX, posY], [velX, velY]]; // current position and velocity of colliding object
var force = [0, n[1]*k*sceneStates[0][1]-b*n[1]*(dot(n, sceneStates[1]))]; // [x,y]
```

I hope this is enough information to let you known where I'm stuck.

Comment: First remark: I think that the specific integration method (RK4) is irrelevant in the question.

Comment: Second: It might be better answered at other SE-s (like game dev or overflow))

Comment: Third: you should try to use mathematical formulas, as the code snippet is of little help in the present form. And also you would be wise to specify the meaning of the vectors in your formula

Comment: I'll see if I can post this elsewhere. I posted something similar on overflow earlier and they said I should ask here. I mentioned RK4 to give a complete idea of what I'm working with. The code snippet is just what I have, I'm not sure how else I can explain what I have and what the context is (math/physics are obviously not my strong suit)

Comment: Well. First thing you should do is to explain more clearly what you are trying to do: are there actual springs simulated? Or you are only using them as a simple model for contact forces when two bodies touch?

Comment: Secondly, what does the letters mean? V is, i suppose the velocity, n maybe the normal of the surface? But what does d and b mean?

Comment: The springs are used a simple model for the contact forces I think, yes.
This is what the letters mean: n is the contact normal, k and b are the spring damping coefficients, d is the desired distance of seperation, and v is the relative velocity between the two points connected by the spring.

Comment: Is this a spring-mass system with collisions, or a mass with collisions that need to be modeled as springs?

Comment: A mass with collisions that need to modeled as springs, I think. All I want to do is make two objects collide, and I've found that collision response with springs was an easy method to do that

Comment: @Dries - the problem is that you need to drop the time integration step three orders of magnitude during each contact in order to make a realistic spring based collision model. An impulse based approach is going to be far faster and more realistic. See these notes [1](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~baraff/sigcourse/notesd1.pdf) and [2](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~baraff/sigcourse/notesd2.pdf) on an overview of simulating rigid bodies with collisions.

Comment: @ja72 Thanks! I'll have a look at those links!

Comment: @Dries I noticed the wikipedia page has pulled images and equations from those two lecture notes. Consider them **the** game developers guide to simulation.

Comment: @ja72 Ah, yes, I see the images on the Collision Response article are indeed the same. Thanks for pointing that out